# problem understanding "this" in a classic and arrow function called as callback

Tags: javascript

I recently face a problem that I can understand yet. Is about the `this` keyword difference in a classical function vs. arrow function **but** when it is called as callback. Let me example that:

**Ex. 1**

```js
class ProductController {
    static property = "hello world"
    
    static findAll() {
        console.log(this.property)
    }
}


// Function that calls findAll
const router = function( callback ) {
    callback()
}
```

**Ex. 1, call 1:**
If I call this function normally as `ProductController.findAll()` output will be: `hello world`. All okay.

**Ex. 1, call 2:**
If I call this function as callback like `router(ProductController.findAll)` output will be: `Cannot read property 'property' of undefined`

In this call 2, `this` is `undefined` because the `findAll` function is passed as value to the router (I guess) where the this reference is loosed, right? **All good here.**

---

Now let's took a variant of this code using arrow functions, as follows:

**Ex. 2**

```js
class ProductController {
    static property = "hello world"
    
    static findAll = () => {
        console.log(this.property)
    }
}


// Function that calls findAll
const router = function( callback ) {
    callback()
}
```

**Ex. 2, call 1:** If I call this function normally as `ProductController.findAll()`output will be: `hello world`. It's fine.

**Ex. 2, call 2:** If I call this function as callback like: `router( ProductController.findAll )` output will be: `hello world`. **WTF, I can't understand this behavior!**

In call 2, I guess the function is passed as value and not by reference so I can't understand why `this` still references to the class...

---

Help understanding that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I call this function as callback like: router( ProductController.findAll ) output will be: hello world. WTF, I can't understand this behavior!

Arrow functions generally inherit their `this` from the outer scope. For static members which are arrow functions (which is very new syntax!), the `this` is the class itself. You can think of the second example code like this:

```
class ProductController {
    static property = "hello world"
    
    static findAll = () => {
        console.log(that.property)
    }
}
const that = ProductController;
```

Or like this psuedocode:

```
class ProductController {
    using (this as ProductController) {
        this.property = "hello world"
        this.findAll = () => {
            console.log(this.property);
        }
    }
}
```

Since it's defined with an arrow function, it doesn't matter how `callback()` happens to be called - the `this` is determined solely from where the function is declared, and not from how it may be passed around as a callback.

Comment: Thanks! that helps. Something that troubles me now is the fact that the **Ex. 2 both calls** actually doesn't work in typescript. I get: `'this' cannot be referenced in a static property initializer.`

Comment: Interesting, see here for discussions on it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36267 It's a complicated issue